# WCF\ASP.NET interoperability

Tags: asp.net

I have a server application written in WCF using asynchronous callbacks, and a webforms application in ASP.NET.
All of the communication is fine between the 2 applications, I can call the exposed functions in the server via the web application, and the server can send callbacks to the web application, however sometimes the functions within the callback work, and other times, they don't.

For example, I would like a login button on the web app to send a username and password to the server, the server checks this against the database, and if the login information is correct, it should send a callback, which opens a new page in the web app.

Here is the relevant server code:

```
public void Login(String username, String password)
{
    //DoCheckAgainstDatabase(username, password);

    ICallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallback>();
    callback.LoginSuccess();
}
```

and the web application code:

```
private InstanceContext _instanceContext;
private ServiceClient _service;
public CallbackHandler MyCallbackHandler = new CallbackHandler();


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _instanceContext = new InstanceContext(MyCallbackHandler);
    _backEnd = new ServiceClient(_instanceContext, "NetTcpBinding_IAU", "net.tcp://localhost/MyService/Service");
    _backEnd.Open();
    MyCallbackHandler.LoginSucceeded += OnLoginSucceeded;
}


protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _backEnd.Login(UsernameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text);
}

private void OnLoginSucceeded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "OpenClientWindow", "window.open('Client.aspx','_self');", true);
}
```

I can put in breakpoints, and see that everything is working fine, it's just that the code 'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript...' does not execute properly all the time.

Could this be something to do with threading? Could anyone suggest a way to fix this please?

Thanks in advance!
David

Comment: Do you mean that `OnLoginSucceeded` doesn't always get called, or that it does but the `RegisterStartupScript` doesn't always have the desired effect?

Comment: OnLoginSucceeded gets called fine every time, it's the RegisterStartupScript that doesn't always have the desired effect.

Comment: It may be that OnLoginSucceeded sometimes fires after the page has gone into the Render stage and rendered its output. In that case, you wouldn't get your startup script.  You could test this by putting a breakpoint or a Debug.WriteLine in the PreRender event handler and seeing if it ever happens before the OnLoginSucceeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs to me that it's possible your page life cycle may be ending - or at least getting to the Render stage, which is where the start up script would be written to the output - before the callback is called.

Is it possible to call your service synchronously, and not proceed out of `LoginButton_Click` until the service call returns?

Comment: I think you were right about this, I've posted amended code below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing script tag - wrap your window.oppen with it, like

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "OpenClientWindow", "<script>window.open('Client.aspx','_self');</script>", true);
```

Comment: Hi, that didn't seem to fix the issue, still not working as I'd expect it to

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ann L. for guidance on this. I have added a ManualResetEvent, and then in the button click method, I wait until I have received the callback, then proceed with opening the new page:

```
private InstanceContext _instanceContext;
private ServiceClient _service;
public CallbackHandler MyCallbackHandler = new CallbackHandler();
private ManualResetEvent _resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _instanceContext = new InstanceContext(MyCallbackHandler);
    _backEnd = new ServiceClient(_instanceContext, "NetTcpBinding_IAU", "net.tcp://localhost/MyService/Service");
    _backEnd.Open();
    MyCallbackHandler.LoginSucceeded += OnLoginSucceeded;
}


protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _backEnd.Login(UsernameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text);
    _resetEvent.WaitOne();

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "OpenClientWindow", "window.open('Client.aspx','_self');", true);
}

private void OnLoginSucceeded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _resetEvent.Set();
}
```